# How to set time limit in Vue-timepicker?

Tags: vuejs2, timepicker, vuejs-datepicker

I am vue-timepicker in my project and below is the code for a component. I want to limit the time from 9:00 AM to 5:00 PM PST?
Is that  usingpossible in vue-timepicker component? If yes, Please help me to do it.

```
<vue-timepicker class="nopad full-width" format="hh:mm A" v-model="guest.time" v-validate="'required'" data-vv-name="time" :minute-interval="30"></vue-timepicker>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please upgrade `vue2-timepicker` to the [latest version](https://github.com/phoenixwong/vue2-timepicker/releases/latest). We added an `hour-range` support since **v.0.2.0** which completely fulfills your needs.

In your case, you can set the `hour-range` to:

```html
<vue-timepicker class="nopad full-width"
    format="hh:mm A"
    :hour-range="[['9a', '5p']]"
    v-model="guest.time"
    v-validate="'required'"
    data-vv-name="time"
    :minute-interval="30"></vue-timepicker>
```

Please note that the `:hour-range="[['9a', '5p']]"` is a shortcut of `:hour-range="['9a', '10a', '11a', '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p']"`.

You can check the [Demo page](https://phoenixwong.github.io/vue2-timepicker/#hourRange) and [Documentation](https://github.com/phoenixwong/vue2-timepicker/blob/master/README.md#define-hour-range) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as this was asked long ago, I found and substitute for it. Though many thanks.

Comment: NP :-) Sorry for not being able to see your question earlier! @MurtazaBharmal